# class get color from id

Tags: html, css

i have few divs that are in same class and have diffrent id's. I need to change color for each div, and i don't know how to do it

I would like to have something like this

HTML code:

```
<div class="thing" id="one"></div>
<div class="thing" id="two"></div>
<div class="thing" id="three"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
#one{
color:green;
}

#two{
color:red;
}

.thing{
background-color: get color from id;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You just did it when you posted your code here.

Comment: Is there a reason for setting the background color in class identifier rather than the id identifier? #one{ background-color:  green; }

Comment: you are looking for `background-color: currentColor`

Answer (score 0):

color - changing the text color

background-color - change the background of the element

Change all 'color' to 'background-color' and see if this is what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using color directly, you can use variables.

```
#one {
  --thing-color: green;
}
#two {
  --thing-color: red;
}
.thing {
  color: var(--thing-color);
  background-color: var(--thing-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.things{border-size = 10px} //for all element in class .things`

`#one{border-color = #blue} //for specific element id one`

id element inherit by default

Answer (score -1):

Could just set inline style for background colour for each?

```
<div class="thing" id="one" style="background: green;"></div>
<div class="thing" id="two" style="background: red;"></div>
<div class="thing" id="three" style="background: blue;"></div>
```

When I tested this it worked using `background: red;` and `background-color: red;`

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is using 'color' in the IDs instead of 'background-color'. This overrides the class' background color, if any.

```
#one{
    background-color: green;
}

#two{
    background-color: red;
}

#three{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but my example was simpified, in div i have few divs with other parameters like border, background color, and i cannot write border in id, because each 'small' div have diffrent settings for borders

Comment: @OstryJR Just setting `border-color` should do the trick then.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS pseudo element as first-child, last-child, nth-child(n)

```
.thing:first-child{
    background-color: green;
}

.thing:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}

.thing:last-child{
    background-color: blue;
}
```